# I have installed darknet for yolo (CPU version) but it is not using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolo, darknet

```
darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights
```

I used this command in CMD, and I got the following error

```
GPU isn't used
 OpenCV isn't used - data increase will run slowly
Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images.
```

Answer (score 3):

refer to [Installing Darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/)

first, open Makefile to modify some options

```
# before
GPU=0
CUDNN=0
CUDNN_HALF=0
OPENCV=0
...
# after
GPU=1
CUDNN=0
CUDNN_HALF=0
OPENCV=1
```

second, recompile it

```
make
```